# Regex in Java to deal with control sequences

Tags: java, regex

I have Strings like

```
'(123-inf]\\\\\'
'\\\'\(12.3-430-1]\\\'
'\\\'\(inf-12.23)\\\\'
'123-123.3]
```

How to remove anything preceded by `(` - including `(` and anything followed by either `)` or `]` - including both character.

Comment: I suspect this is homework. While some users on SO may be happy to help you with homework, 
I think you should at least show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Dear, it is not a home work, I tried it differently with indexOf(string) method but there were thousands of strings token and every one have different sequence

Comment: Yes, you definitely need a regex for that. Here are links to the [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html). Read them, and if you get stuck somewhere specific, come back and ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `replaceAll`

```
string.replaceAll("^.*\\(|[)\\]].*", "");
```

Comment: Thank You so much, would you please help me that what if I want to remove anything preceded by '[' at the start as well ?

Comment: try `string.replaceAll("^.*[\\[(]|[)\\]].*", "");`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help